# Topological modules and relative homological algebra.

Tags: functional-analysis, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, banach-algebras, locally-convex-spaces

This question might be a bit dumb but I'm tired right now and this is just going over my head at the moment, in "The homology of Banach and topological algebras" Helemskii said that relative homological algebra can be used to define certain homological concepts in categories of locally convex modules, he refers to this paper by Taylor (http://bit.ly/1BeS6q5), I was reading this paper but there are a couple of things I was confused about:

- There's a map $\epsilon: C \rightarrow A$ defined on page 141, but what is $C$?
- I went to page 146 where Taylor says:

> Note that our projective modules are not projective objects in the
>   category of all $A$-modules. They are, however, relative projectives
>   in the sense of chapter 13 of "Homology" by Sanders Mac Lane, if the
>   class of allowable short exact sequences is taken to be the class of
>   $C$-split short exact sequences.

In the context of relative homological algebra a relative projective is a $\square$-allowable projective objet $P$ in some abelian category $\mathcal{A}$, where $\square$ is a covariant functor between two abelian categories $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ which is additive, exact and faitful, if in this case $\mathcal{A}$ is the category of all $A$-modules, What is the abelian category $\mathcal{B}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your question on notation in Taylor's paper $C$ means the field of complex numbers and $\epsilon$ stands for the natural embedding of $C$ into unital algebra $A$.

As for the deinition of relative homology you must understand that you can't transfer Mac Lane's definition word by word to the realm of topological modules for one simple reason - their categories are not abelian. But you don't need to do so!

In fact you don't need to put any restrictions on $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ in order for this definition to work. For example if you take $\mathcal{A}$ as category of compact Hausdorff topological spaces, $\mathcal{B}$ the category of all sets and $\square:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$ as obvious forgetful functor, then $\square$-allowable projective Husdorff topological spaces are extremelly disconnected compact spaces. This result is due to [Rainwater](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1971-028-01/S0002-9939-1971-0271907-5/S0002-9939-1971-0271907-5.pdf), but, of course, he hasn't used such fancy language.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond, thanks for the answer, so here $\mathcal{A}$ = the category of locally convex $A$-modules = **$A$-mod**, and $\mathcal{B}$ = the category of $C$-modules (relative to $\widetilde{\otimes}$) = topological vector spaces over $C$ (which are not abelian categories, but they are additive). Honestly, what I wanted to know was if the category of chain complexes in **$A$-mod** has the structure of a model category.

Comment: Unfortunately, I now nothing on model categories.

Comment: That's fine thanks, but back to my original question, the one thing I don't understand is why would Taylor say that his theory is an example of relative homological algebra if it isn't? There's a class of allowable short exact sequences but the categories involved $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are additive, but Mac Lane defines relative homological algebra, relative abelian categories, and allowable short exact sequences when the categories involved are abelian, or I guess it doesn't matter since the techniques are still useful if we want to do homological algebra in this context?

Comment: In times of MacLane no one bothered too much about non-abelian categories, this is reason why MacLane gave his definition for abelian categories, though it works in much wider context.

Comment: It's a lot more clear now, thanks again.